# Issue with scanning a character from a file

Tags: c, file, input, character

An issue with my code has risen up in the matter of scanning in characters from a file. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    char check, key;
    char buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    char str[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    node *head = NULL;

    fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer);
    head = stringToList(buffer);

    while(fscanf(ifp, "%c", &check) != EOF){
        switch(check){
        case '@':
            //fflush(stdin);            //this is commented out because fflush
            fscanf(ifp, "%c", &key);         //did not seem to solve the issue
            fscanf(ifp, "%s", str);
            printf("%c, %s\n", key, str);
            head = replaceChar(head, key, str);
            break;

        //more cases follow, but they are irrelevant to this question
```

My issue here is that my program is failing to scan in a character to key when called. When the input for the particular case from the file says, for example,

```
@ r ri
```

The print statement gives the following:

```
( ), (r)
```

There is a blank space in the print statement which should print r, and as far as I can tell the character is instead scanning into the string. Thus the program is dysfunctional. I need to know how to properly scan in this character. Thank you.

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, " %c", &key);` then `fscanf(ifp, " %s", str);` notice the additional `space`s. You are reading a `' '` after reading the `'@'`.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe that worked. Thank you.

Comment: When you read a character at a time, you really do read every character.... Why do you want to discriminate against the poor little `space`? It's a `char` too (0x20 or 30 decimal). You might make it feel bad, give it a complex or something `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fscanf(ifp, " %c", &key);` then `fscanf(ifp, " %s", str);` notice the additional `space`s. You are reading a `' '` after reading the `'@'`. – [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin)

This has answered my question. Pretty strange that C would be messed up by something so simple.

Comment: Note: The space before `"%s"` is not needed and is not part of the problem/solution.